# Is drupal a good solution for websites with a very dynamic layout?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7

I'm looking to use Drupal from an upcoming project as I've always been very interested in using it. However the more I get familiar the more I feel that Drupal isn't a good solution for a website that is very dynamic in terms of page-to-page layout alterations and just generally dynamic elements in pages.

For example, the front page of the website is going to have a newsletter signup form with 2 steps, which should be done through Ajax. Just to achieve this I've already had to install like 5 modules to get the right behaviour. And at this point I don't feel it's very user-friendly for end-users who are going to be using the CMS once it's delivered.

My question is simple, am I wrong in assuming that Drupal really isn't the right solution for this type of website? And if I am, what is the conventional approach developers take to the implementation of solutions such as the one I mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes you'll want to build custom modules instead of installing a bunch of ones that sort-of do what you want.

Comment: Of course, that's the case for any CMS really. But I feel the example I gave is pretty generic, so generic in fact that a CMS as big as Drupal should have an easier way to achieve it. I'm simply wondering if I'm missing something or if Drupal is not what I thought it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal is highly customizable, but yes takes a lot of work to get set up to do what you'd like. Other CMS' provide much simpler out of the box style 'install this addon through an interface and fuhgeddaboudit' type of solutions for the more layman user. Wordpress and Joomla come to mind.
 If you want to go a more developer oriented route I would suggest one of the many php frameworks out there. [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) are a few popular ones, but there are tons of them out there. Play around with them and see which is better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I used a lot of CMS'es and all are not fine.. dirty code in them etc. and most of them are slow... Drupal is a complex solution for you and it seems ok...

You need to learn how to make modules.. it isn't that hard if you know some php...

You can modify each template .. each page.. it's not so complicated.. just try to learn some..

P.S: You can use the views in order to not write code..you might do something with them...

Answer (score 0):

It's about 20 lines of PHP code in Agile Toolkit. No extra javascript, no extra HTML, no plugins:

Demo: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/newsletter

Source: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/source/newsletter